# Save to join table and regular table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

Want form to create Test record which references Questions. So a Test has many questions and a Question has many tests. When the form submits it is creating the Test record but is saying the question parameter is unpermitted. But also the question param shouldn't be saved to Test it should be saved to my `questions_tests` table. How do you do this? That way I can show a Test with the questions that were chosen by the form.

Models:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions_tests
  has_many :questions, :through => :questions_tests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :test_questions
  has_many :tests, :through => :questions_tests
end
class QuestionTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Controllers:

```
#tests_controller.rb
def create
respond_to do |format|
    if test = Test.create(test_params)
      @test = []
      @test << test
      question_test = @test.find(test.id)
      format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @test }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
def test_params
    params.require(:test).permit(:name, :user_id, :type, :category, :description, :question, question_attributes: [ :id, :content, :category ] ).
    merge user_id: current_user.id
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :type %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :type %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category %><br>
<%= f.select :category, [ ["one", "one"], ["two", "two"] ], {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :question %><br>
  <%= f.fields_for :question do |question| %>
  <%= question.collection_select :question_id, Question.where({ category: "ip_voice" }), :id, :content, {prompt: "Select Question"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/tests" for x at 2014-05-07 14:34:59 -0400
Processing by TestsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x=", "test"=>{"name"=>"thoo", "type"=>"", "category"=>"one", "description"=>"chickens on the road", "question"=>{"question_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Test"}
Unpermitted parameters: question
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'ca9a73ab72a94f538723de34856a92dcde068e7b' LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tests" ("category", "created_at", "description", "name", "type", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["category", "ip_voice"], ["created_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 18:34:59 UTC +00:00], ["description", "chickens on the road"], ["name", "thoo"], ["type", ""], ["updated_at", Wed, 07 May 2014 18:34:59 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
(17.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/tests/11
Completed 302 Found in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 17.7ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Test` has_many `questions`.

You would need to update the `test_params` method to reflect that:

```
def test_params
    params.require(:test).permit(:name, :user_id, :type, :category, :description, questions_attributes: [ :id, :content, :category ] ).
    merge user_id: current_user.id
end
```

You don't need `:question` here unless you have an attribute named `question` in `tests` table. Also, you should be using `questions_attributes` (Notice **plural questions**) and NOT `question_attributes` (Notice **singular question**)

On the same lines, you need to update the `fields_for` in your view as below:

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |question| %>
```

`:questions` (Notice **plural questions**) and NOT `:question` (Notice **singular question**)

**UPDATE**

The join model of `Test` and `Question` is named `QuestionTest` so you should be referring it in associations as `question_tests` (For `has_many`)

You have incorrectly setup the associations, update them as below:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_tests  ## "question_tests" and NOT "questions_tests"
  has_many :questions, :through => :question_tests  ## "question_tests" and NOT "questions_tests"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :question_tests   ## "question_tests" and NOT "test_questions"
  has_many :tests, :through => :question_tests   ## "question_tests" and NOT "questions_tests"
end
```

**Implemented Solution:** Hope this helps anyone needing similar results.

tests_controller.rb

```
def new
  @test = Test.new
end
def create
  @test = Test.new(test_params)
  @test.save
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :question %><br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :question_ids, Question.all.to_a.collect, :id, :content %>
  </div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Schema for join table, ensure you don't have `id:false`:

```
create_table "question_tests", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "test_id",     null: false
  t.integer "question_id", null: false
end
```

Comment: uninitialized constant Test::QuestionsTest for f.fields_for :questions line

Comment: Read the `UPDATE` section in my answer.

Comment: The plural stuff is confusing! Thanks! :D